# Why region_name is required for some aws services in boto3.client while using regional endpoint?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-regions

Why do we need to provide **region_name** if we are already using **regional endpoints**?

And also, If I don't specify **region_name** for sqs then It'll give an Error `(NoRegionError : You must specify a region)`. While creating client for s3, **region_name** is not required.

```
client = boto3.client(
    "sqs",
    aws_access_key_id=key_id,
    aws_secret_access_key=secret_key,
    aws_session_token=token,
    endpoint_url="https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
    region_name="us-east-1",  # For some reason region name is required here
)

client = boto3.client(
    "s3",
    aws_access_key_id=key_id,
    aws_secret_access_key=secret_key,
    aws_session_token=token,
    endpoint_url="https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com", # While this works perfect
    )
```

Comment: Because the `region_name` is used to construct the endpoint URL in the botocore, but it's not the other way around.

Comment: S3 existed before AWS had multiple regions. I'm guessing backwards compatibility.